# PHP zip file downloads locally but not in production

Tags: php

I am working on some files to download in a zip. Works fine locally but not in any environment (staging or production). Using WP VIP also, not sure if that helps. I'm a little new to VIP. Really racked by brains here and can't seem to figure out the issue.

I've read the resources on PHP zip creation. I do get the "Unable to add zip file.', 500 );" error producing.

Code below:

```
$context = [];
$post = theme()->twig()->create_post();

$tab_index = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'tab-index', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
$content_calendar = $post->get_field('content_calendar');
if ( ! isset( $content_calendar[ $tab_index ] ) ) {
    \wp_send_json_error( 'Invalid tab-index.', 400 );
    exit;
}

$tab = $content_calendar[ $tab_index ];
// Create zip name;
$name = 'content-calendar-' . $tab_index;

$group_index = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'group-index', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
if ( null !== $group_index ) {
    if ( ! isset( $tab['groups'][ $group_index ] ) ) {
        \wp_send_json_error( 'Invalid group-index.', 400 );
        exit;
    }

    $groups = [ $tab['groups'][ $group_index ] ];
    // Append group to name
    $name .= '-' . $group_index;
} else {
    $groups = $tab['groups'];
}

// Extract paths from resources with assets
$paths = [];
foreach ( $groups as $group ) {
    foreach ( $group['resources'] as $resource ) {
        if ( $resource['social_resource'] ) {
            $asset_id = get_field( 'asset', $resource['social_resource'] );
            if ( $asset_id ) {
                $paths[] = get_attached_file( $asset_id, true );
            }
        }
    }
}

// Remove invalid or duplicate URLs
$paths = array_unique( array_filter( $paths ) );

if ( empty( $paths ) ) {
    \wp_send_json_error( 'No files to download.', 400 );
    exit;
}

// Generate file names
$zipfile = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/' . $name . '.zip';
$zipname = $name . '-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.zip';


// Generate file
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ( true !== $zip->open( $zipfile, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE ) ) {
    \wp_send_json_error( 'Unable to create zip file.', 500 );
    exit;
}

foreach ( $paths as $path ) {
    if ( true !== $zip->addFile( $path, basename( $path ) ) ) {
        $zip->close();
        \wp_send_json_error( 'Unable to add file to zip.', 500 );
        exit;
    }
}
$zip->close();


// Send headers and stream file
header( 'Content-Type: application/zip' );
header( 'Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipname );
header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $zipfile ) );
readfile( $zipfile );
exit;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check you production destination directory permissions, the user that the web service runs under will need access and write permissions all the way up to and including that folder to be able to write to it

Comment: Check that the directory have write permissions and the directory already exist also check if zip extension is already installed on production server

Comment: The directory the files are suppose to be downloaded from is the wp-content/uploads folder.